# How to avoid calling toVector on each Scala for comprehension / yield?

Tags: scala, yield, for-comprehension

I have several methods that operate on `Vector` sequences and the following idiom is common when combining data from multiple vectors into a single one with the use of a for comprehension / yield:

```
(for (i <- 0 until y.length) yield y(i) + 0.5*dy1(i)) toVector
```

Notice the closing `toVector` and the enclosing parentheses around the for comprehension. I want to get rid of it because it's ugly, but removing it produces the following error:

```
type mismatch;
 found   : scala.collection.immutable.IndexedSeq[Double]
 required: Vector[Double]
```

Is there a better way of achieving what I want that avoids explicitly calling `toVector` many times to essentially achieve a non-operation (converting and indexed sequence...to an indexed sequence)?

Answer (score 1):

One way to avoid collection casting, e.g. `toVector`, is to invoke, if possible, only those methods that return the same collection type.

```
y.zipWithIndex.map{case (yv,idx) => yv + 0.5*dy1(idx)}
```

Comment: Neat, didn't think of the fact that `zipWithIndex` should  have this property

Answer (score 0):

**`for yield` on `Range` which you are using in your example yields a `Vector[T]` by default.**

example,

```
scala> val squares= for (x <- Range(1, 3)) yield x * x
squares: scala.collection.immutable.IndexedSeq[Int] = Vector(1, 4)
```

check the type,

```
scala> squares.isInstanceOf[Vector[Int]]
res14: Boolean = true
```

Note that `Vector[T]` also extends `IndexedSeq[T]`.

```
@SerialVersionUID(-1334388273712300479L)
final class Vector[+A] private[immutable] (private[collection] val startIndex: Int, private[collection] val endIndex: Int, focus: Int)
extends AbstractSeq[A]
   with IndexedSeq[A]
   with GenericTraversableTemplate[A, Vector]
   with IndexedSeqLike[A, Vector[A]]
   with VectorPointer[A @uncheckedVariance]
   with Serializable
   with CustomParallelizable[A, ParVector[A]]
```

That's why above result is also an instance of `IndexedSeq[T]`,

```
scala> squares.isInstanceOf[IndexedSeq[Int]]
res15: Boolean = true
```

You can define the type of your result as `IndexedSeq[T]` and still achieve what you want with `Vector` without explicitly calling `.toVector`

```
scala> val squares: IndexedSeq[Int] = for (x <- Range(1, 3)) yield x * x
squares: IndexedSeq[Int] = Vector(1, 4)

scala> squares == Vector(1, 4)
res16: Boolean = true
```

**But for yield on `Seq[T]` gives `List[T]` by default.**

```
scala> val squares = for (x <- Seq(1, 3)) yield x * x
squares: Seq[Int] = List(1, 9)
```

Only in that case if you want vector you must `.toVector` the result.

```
scala> squares.isInstanceOf[Vector[Int]]
res21: Boolean = false

scala> val squares = (for (x <- Seq(1, 3)) yield x * x).toVector
squares: Vector[Int] = Vector(1, 9)
```

Comment: Your comment makes it out as if the error should just not be happening, could you edit it just a bit so it's clearer initially which issues from my question you're addressing directly?